# Pop-up is getting blocked when calling displayNewMessageFormAsync

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

In an Outlook web Add-in I'm calling the `displayNewMessageFormAsync` method of the Office JS API to display a new form for e-mail creation and filling the e-mail's to filled with the given e-mail address. However on Safari and Firefox if I don't allow pop-ups, these browser will block the opening of this new form. On the other side in Chrome it opens the new form without explicitly allowing pop-ups in the browser.

**My Code:**

```
  private addRecipientToNewMail(recipient: string): void {
    this.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync({ toRecipients: [recipient] },
    (result: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log(result.error);
      }
    });
  }
```

It's interesting if I call the `displayNewMessageFormAsync` method with a `parameters` argument where I set the `htmlBody` property, then on Firefox the new form will be displayed without allowing pop-ups explicitly, code example:

```
this.mailbox.displayNewMessageFormAsync({ htmlBody: `<h1>Test</h1>` }, 
(result: Office.AsyncResult<void>) => {
  if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
    console.log(result.error);
  }
});
```

**Tested browsers:**

- Google Chrome - Version 111.0.5563.64
- Safari - Version 15.6.1 (15613.3.9.1.16)
- Firefox - 110.0.1

I would like to have a solution for this issue where the new e-mail form can be opened directly without having to enable pop-ups manually in the browser.

Comment: Sounds like an issue in the OfficeJS, so I'd suggest posting this as a bug to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues .

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev thanks for the advice, I've created a bug report for this issue which can be viewed here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3213

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Internal tracking id: 196034